# Publish a message from Vernemq plugin

Tags: erlang, mqtt

I want to convert an HTTP request to MQTT request. So for that I received the HTTP request which consist of the information like topic and message to publish. I have to publish the provided message to provided topic.

I am able to publish the message but the problem is that I can only provide the Topic and Payload to the function I used. Here is the piece of code I write to publish:

```
Data = mochiweb_request:parse_post(Req),
{RegisterFun, PublishFun, SubscribeFun} = vmq_reg:direct_plugin_exports(http_to_mqtt),
Topic    = get_value("topic", Data),
List_of_topics = string:tokens(Topic, "/"),
Lot = lists:map(fun(X) -> list_to_binary(X) end, List_of_topics),
Payload  = list_to_binary(get_value("message", Data)),
error_logger:info_msg("Topics: ~p~nPayload: ~p",[Lot, Payload]),
PublishFun(Lot,Payload),
Req:ok({"text/html", [], "<p>Thank you. <p>"})
```

Here the PublishFun I get from the vmq_reg can only allow to give topic and message. Is there any other way I can publish a message giving the value to Qos, Retain and Dup also.

I am creating a server using mochiweb and use it as a plugin in vernemq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible in the new release of VerneMQ as stated by Andre.

Here is how it works :

```
Data = mochiweb_request:parse_post(Req),
{RegisterFun,PublishFun,SubscribeFun} = vmq_reg:direct_plugin_exports(http_to_mqtt),
Topic    = get_value("topic", Data),
List_of_topics = string:tokens(Topic, "/"),
Lot = lists:map(fun(X) -> list_to_binary(X) end, List_of_topics),
Payload  = list_to_binary(get_value("message", Data)),
Qos = erlang:list_to_integer(get_value("qos",Data)),
Retain = erlang:list_to_integer(get_value("retain",Data)),
error_logger:info_msg("Topics: ~p~nPayload: ~p~nQOS: ~p~nRetain: ~p",[Lot, Payload,Qos,Retain]),
PublishFun(Lot,Payload,#{qos => Qos, retain => Retain}),
Req:ok({"text/html", [], "<p>Thank you. <p>"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the current version, but a planned feature for the future.

Comment: Are there any updates regarding this issue. Can you please help me its urgent.

Comment: please get in touch over email.